# How to programmatically look up a symbol in a running application

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have an application which I'm trying to debug, however running it under gdb is producing different results, and it would be nice to have it output true symbol information when confronted with an address. for instance.

I have a method which is called periodically and I can determine the address of the call site. However, I'd like to print out the symbol information at run time for this address. I know I can run "nm" on the executable but that is outside of the application. I want to be able to do it from within the application itself.

I'm using GCC 4.7.2 on a linux platform.

(eddited to explain why I can't use gdb)

Comment: Why not run the application through a debugger, such as `gdb` ?

Comment: I'm not trying to debug it. I'm wanting to print out the names of symbols from calling methods

Comment: Are these methods or is this C?

Comment: Does `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` give you what you need?

Comment: **From the question:** *"I have an application which I'm trying to debug"*.   **From the comments:** *"I'm not trying to debug it."*     Please come back when you know what you want.

Comment: Yes, apologies for the confusion. I am trying to debug it but every time I run it under gdb I get different results due to memory corruption. I need it to print out method stuff outside of the debugger.

Comment: If you have memory corruption, try `valgrind` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic symbol information can be accessed via the `DT_DYNAMIC` segment, which is loaded into memory and can be accessed by asking `dlopen(3)` for a handle to the main executable.

Static symbol information can be read only from the actual executable file, or an external file, as it is not listed in the loadable segments.

With just dynamic information, you will not be able to resolve anything that is not exported, which means you will most likely only see library calls unless your executable has its symbol table exported, so static information is probably the way to go.

This involves either lots of parsing, or using the `bfd` library built from *binutils*.

I'd seriously wonder if that was really worth the effort, though. You might get the same information from using the profiling support in gcc.